# display more than one column in listView with SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a ListView populated with a SimpleCursorAdapter. The listview shows the content of one column of my database. That column is just lessons I created in my db (like English,Maths). I have also themes for each lesson ( like Reading Writting..). And that is also a column of the same table. In my listView it only shows "English", but I'd like to show "English - Reading", so I can make the difference.

How can I do that ?

btw, my column for the lesson is 'branche_cours' and the other column I want to show is 'designation'.

Here's my SimpleCursorAdapter

```
     lvCours =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListCours);
    final Cursor cursor = dbhelper.getAllCours();
    String[] from = { "branche_cours" }; int[] to = { android.R.id.text1 };
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, from, to, 0);
    lvCours.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I haven't foundthe solution yet guys..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Create a layout `list_item.xml` for your row item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_branche_cours"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="English"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text=" - " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_designation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Reading" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

**2.** To show `branche_cours` to TextView `R.id.text_branche_cours` and `designation` to TextView `R.id.text_designation`, do this in your `Activity`:

```
lvCours = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListCours);
final Cursor cursor = dbhelper.getAllCours();

String[] from = { "branche_cours", "designation" }; 
int[] to = { R.id.text_branche_cours, R.id.text_designation };

adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, cursor, from, to, 0);
lvCours.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Here is an good [Tutorial](https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/).

Hope this will help~

Comment: happy to help :)